# Calculating expected value when certain values turn reward to zero

Tags: probability, expected-value

I am doing a course on probability--

Here is an example from the course which I am quiet confused with calculations for favorable outcomes --

Q is: To determine number of dice ('n') to roll to get optimum expected value. Problem statement is as follows --

*"Suppose we modify a dice rolling game in your favor. You pay 3k(dollars) to play, and now you win and get a  10k(dollars) payoff if you get either a 5 or a 6 , but no 1s; otherwise, you lose. how many dice should you roll to get optimum expected value"*

*(for brevity I am only showing favorable outcome calculation as that is the crux of the solution in my opinion)*

Solution says favorable outcomes are calculated as $(5^n - 3^n)/6^n$
I am trying to understand why favorable outcomes are calculated as $(5^n - 3^n)/6^n$ instead of $(1-4^n)/6^n$.
Isnt  it that Except 5 & 6 other numbers are not favorable.

Or to put it other way. If we get any of the other 4 (1,2,3,4) we end up not getting any reward.

So I am saying if say we were asked

*"Suppose we modify a dice rolling game in your favor. You pay  3k(dollars)  to play, and now you win and get a  10k(dollars) payoff if you get either a  5or6 a , but no 1s & 2s; otherwise, you lose."*

Does the favorable outcomes now become $(4^n - 2^n)/6^n$

Regards

Comment: What is $n$ here?

Comment: n is number of dice rolled

Comment: Where you say "instead of $1-4^n$" there must be a typo.

Comment: $1-4^n$ can't possibly be right since it's negative for $n\ge0$.

Comment: yeah forgot to put total outcomes there :) now edited to reflect same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to count the rolls where at least one $5$ or one $6$ comes up, but no $1$s.  First of all, there are $5^n$ rolls that have no $1$s.  From those, we have to exclude the rolls where no $5$ or $6$ shows up, that is those rolls where the only numbers that come up are $2,3,4$.  There are $3^n$ of these.  This explains the first calculation.

For the second calculation, the same sort of reasoning shows that excluding both $1$s and $2$s does indeed lead to $4^n-2^n$ favorable outcomes.

Comment: so why this confuses me is that... when we say if we roll 2 dice and expect atleast one six, we essentially do 1-5^2/6^2 or for n rolls it will be 1-5^n/6^n. So we eliminate all non favorable outcomes to get favorable outcomes. Why is it not same in the above example?

Comment: We're doing just that, except we're restricting the possible rolls at the beginning.  If you like, you could say that there are two sorts of unfavorable rolls: rolls with a $1$ or rolls will only $2,3,4$.  Then the number of favorable rolls is $6^n-(6^n-5^n)-3^n.$  But that comes to the same thing and, I think, is harder to follow.